# Kali Linux Microsoft Store Issue

Tags: kali-linux

I have just installed 'Kali Linux' from the Microsoft Store, thought it would be a good idea.

I've run

```
apt-get install kali-linux-full
```

And uh, everything installed correctly and all **but** when running airmon-ng I get...

```
ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': No such file or directory

PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset
```

I've been searching everywhere for an answer

Comment: No apology needed. Just letting you know. And yeah, what Nathan said. If you are not a very solid linux user and/or security professional, kali is not for you.

Comment: Lmao, everyone has to start somewhere

Comment: @FilipStolarek totally, but don't start with kali. Ubuntu/ubuntu server, fedora, centos, all widely used in industry and all much, much more accesible. I've been using linux as my daily work OS for years, I've been through the right of passage that is a bare arch install, and I still stick to those.

Comment: It's refreshing to see that the comments here aren't lynching the new fellow. Welcome, Filip. This is StackOverflow, and here it's *mainly* programming Q/A. If you've got a programming question, maybe when you start scripting in Bash, we'd be more than happy to lend a hand! Check in at the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for info on how you should ask here. Don't be discouraged, and have a lovely day! :D

Comment: I suspect its cause WSL dosen't give you full access to your hardware.